# Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

postman.response.txt 
https://gist.github.com/stanislavgr79/e82999e5ae69876f0316280687388a25

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app3",
    data: {
        path: "",
        sortEvent: "",
        eventsValue: [],
    },

    methods: {
        getResponse(){
          this.requestByParam(this.sortEvent);
        },
        requestByParam: function (byParam) {
            this.$http
                .get(this.path, {
                    params: { sortEvent: this.sortEvent },
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        Accept: "application/json",
                    },
                })
                .then((response) =>
                    response.json().then((data) => {
                        let listResultQuery = [];
                        if (data.length == 0) {
                            return;
                        }
                    //    data.forEach((element) => {
                    //   listResultQuery.push(element);
                         // dont work
                    });
                        this.eventsValue = data;
                        this.emptyMessage = "";
                    })
                );
        },
    },
});




 <div id="app3">
        <events_nav path=${resource.path}></events_nav>
        <all_events id="all-events" :eventsValue="eventsValue"></all_events>
</div>
```

i try reformat:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: method_event,
            url: path_event + '.sort.json',
            data: params,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (response, status, request) {
                if (status == 'success') {
                    var output = "";

                    $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                        output += "<div class='span3'>";
                        output += "<h3>" + key + "<i class='events__" + key + "'></i></h3>";

                        $(value).each(function (index, el) {
                            output += "<ul class='icons icons_type'><i class='icon-" + el.topic + "'></i>";
                            output += "<li class='events_type'>";
                            output += "<span class='date' type='date'>" +    formatDate(el.eventStartDate) + "</span>";
                            output += "<h4><a href='"+el.titleLink+"' rel='"+el.typeOfOpen+"'>" + el.title + "</a></h4>";
                            output += el.description;
                            output += "</li></ul>";
                        });
                        output += "</div>";
                        $('#all-events').html(output);
                });
            }
        }
    })
}
```

now i have error :

```
Vue.component("all_events", {
props: {
    eventsValue: Array,
},
template:
    '<div class="span3" v-for="(value, name) in eventList">' +
    '<h3>{{ name }}<i class="events__{{ name }}"></i></h3>' +
    '</div>',
});
```

eventsValue - its Object ????? its Array ???????

what i need to write tempalate to see key

```
$.each(response, function (key, value) {
                        output += "<div class='span3'>";
                        output += "<h3>" + key + "<i class='events__" + key + "'></i></h3>";
```

this method dont work:

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.message">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this dont work:

```
<ul id="example-2">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
    {{ parentMessage }} - {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this dont work:

```
<ul id="v-for-object" class="demo">
  <li v-for="value in object">
    {{ value }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this dont work:

```
<div v-for="(value, name) in object">
  {{ name }}: {{ value }}
</div>
```

and this dont work:

```
<div v-for="(value, name, index) in object">
  {{ index }}. {{ name }}: {{ value }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the error *"Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements"*

You just need to wrap the template in another dom element

example:

```js
Vue.component("all_events", {
props: {
    eventsValue: Array,
},
template:`
<div>
  <div class="span3" v-for="(value, name) in eventList">
    <h3>{{ name }}<i class="events__{{ name }}"></i></h3>
  </div>
</div>
`});
```

try that with the code before you reformatted.

Answer (score 0):

this code works. thanks community and Daniel

```
Vue.component("events_nav", {
    props: {
        dataPath: String,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            sortEvent: "topic",
            topic: true,
            type: false
        };
    },
    methods: {
        requestTopic: function () {
            this.sortEvent = "topic";
            this.$root.sortEvent = this.sortEvent;
            this.topic = true;
            this.type = false;
            this.$root.getResponse();
        },
        requestType: function () {
            this.sortEvent = "type";
            this.$root.sortEvent = this.sortEvent;
            this.topic = false;
            this.type = true;
            this.$root.getResponse();
        },
    },
    created: function () {
        let servletSelector = ".sort";
        let servletExtension = ".json";

        this.$root.dataPath = this.dataPath.concat(
            servletSelector,
            servletExtension
        );
        this.$root.sortEvent = this.sortEvent;
        this.$root.getResponse();
    },
    template:
        '<div class="navbar events_nav">' +
        '<div class="navbar-inner">' +
        '<span class="brand">View By:</span>' +
        '<ul class="nav" id="event_sort" data-sort="topic" data-method="GET" :data-path="dataPath">' +
        '<li :class="{active: topic}" id="events__view-topic"><span @click="requestTopic">Topic</span></li>' +
        '<li :class="{active: type}" id="events__view-type"><span @click="requestType">Type</span></li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>',
});

Vue.component("all-events", {
    props: {
        eventsValue: "",
    },
    template:
        '<div class="row event-listing">' +
        '<div class="span3" v-for="(value, name) in eventsValue">' +
        '<h3>{{ name }}<event-icon :icon="name"></event-icon></h3>' +
        '<event-column :value="value"></event-column>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>',
});


Vue.component("event-icon", {
    props: {
        icon: String,
    },
    computed: {
        classIcon: function () {

            let icon = '';

            if (this.$props.icon == 'Database') {
                icon = 'icon-hdd'
            }
            if (this.$props.icon == 'Cloud') {
                icon = 'icon-cloud'
            }
            if (this.$props.icon == 'Mobile') {
                icon = 'icon-mobile-phone'
            }
            if (this.$props.icon == 'Other Topics') {
                icon = 'icon-calendar'
            }

            return icon;
        }
    },
    template:
        '<i :class="classIcon"></i>',
});

Vue.component("event-column", {
    props: {
        value: Array,
    },
    template:
        '<ul class="unstyled" >' +
        '<li class="event-list" v-for="item in this.$props.value">' +
        '<element-event :element="item"></element-event>' +
        '</li>' +
        '</ul>',
});

Vue.component("element-event", {
    props: {
        element: Object,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            description: "",
            eventdate: ""
        };
    },
    computed: {
        classIcon: function () {

            let icon = '';

            if (this.$props.element.topic == 'Database') {
                icon = 'icon-hdd'
            }
            if (this.$props.element.topic == 'Cloud') {
                icon = 'icon-cloud'
            }
            if (this.$props.element.topic == 'Mobile') {
                icon = 'icon-mobile-phone'
            }
            if (this.$props.element.topic == 'Other Topics') {
                icon = 'icon-calendar'
            }

            return icon;
        },
        selectTopic: function () {
            let result = false;
            if (this.$root.sortEvent == "type") {
                result = true;
            }

            return result;
        }

    },
    methods: {
        formatDate() {
            return new Date(this.$props.element.eventStartDate).toLocaleString('en-US', {
                day: '2-digit',
                month: 'long'
            });
        },
    },
    template:
        '<div>' +
        '<i v-if="selectTopic" class="icon" v-bind:class="classIcon"></i>' +
        '<span class="date" type="date" v-html="formatDate()"></span>' +
        '<h4><a :href="element.titleLink" :rel="element.typeOfOpen" v-html="element.title"></a></h4>' +
        '<p class="event-description" v-html="element.description"></p>' +
        '</div>',

})

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#eventviewer-v2",
    data: {
        dataPath: "",
        sortEvent: "",
        events: "",
    },

    methods: {
        getResponse() {
            this.requestByParam(this.sortEvent);
        },
        requestByParam: function (byParam) {
            this.$http
                .get(this.dataPath, {
                    params: { sortEvent: this.sortEvent },
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        Accept: "application/json",
                    },
                })
                .then((response) =>
                    response.json().then((data) => {
                        this.events = data;
                        this.emptyMessage = "";
                    })
                );
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove wrap element...

```
mounted () {
  this.$el.replaceWith(...this.$el.childNodes)
}
```